# Как получить только версию windows без доп

Tags: c#

В наличие есть рабочий код:

```
public static string GetWindowsWMI()
{
   string nameos = string.Empty;
   using (ManagementObjectCollection collection = new 
   ManagementObjectSearcher(@"root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem").Get())
   {
      foreach (ManagementBaseObject managementBase in collection)
      {
        nameos = managementBase["Caption"].ToString();
      }
   }
   return nameos;
}
```

Он мне выводит по такому принципу: `Майкрософт Windows 10 Pro`

Как мне получить именования по такому принципу: `Windows 10`, `Windows 7`, `Windows 8.1` и.т.д

Comment: По-хорошему нужно смотреть свойство `Version`. И смотреть по таблице: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ver_(%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Comment: [Detect Windows version in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819974)